# RxJava how to intersperse a Flowable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-streams

I'm new to `rx-java`, I'm comming from the `akka` world. In `akka-streams` there is a convinient [intersperse](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.7/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#intersperse%5BT%3E:Out%5D(start:T,inject:T,end:T):FlowOps.this.Repr%5BT%5D) function and I would like to know how to do the same on `Flowable`? so something like

```
Flowable
 .fromIterable(List("foo","bar"))
 .intersperse("[", "," ,"]")
```

which would output: `[foo,bar]`

I have a some big data streamed from a DB to convert as a JSON array and that would be super useful.

currently I found:

```
Flowable....
   .startWith(Flowable.just("["))
   .concatWith(Flowable.just("]"))
```

Don't know if it's a clean way, but now I just miss the in between comma

Edit:
I have a working solution with

```
Flowable....
   .concatMap(str => Flowable.just(str, ",")
   .skipLast(1) 
   .startWith(Flowable.just("["))
   .concatWith(Flowable.just("]"))
```

But still, it seems it could be easier no?

Comment: That's the simplest way of doing it.

Comment: ok thx a lot. Would it make sense to add a proper `intersperse` function to rxjava API?

Comment: It is a very uncommon operator for us so no.